# Passing Addresses in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-address

I'm new to C and having some trouble with pointers. I want to pass a pointer address to another function, then pass the address in that function into a third function. Here is an example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Coordinate;

int main()
{
    Coordinate location;
    functA(&location);
    printf("Value of x: %d\n", location.x); //prints 10
    printf("Value of y: %d\n", location.y); //prints 20
}

void functA(Coordinate *location)
{
    location->x = 10;
    location->y = 20; 
}
```

This is a simplified part of the code I currently have. Lets say I want `functA` to call another function that reduces the values in the structe in half, I tried doing this but it dosen't seem to work,

```
void functA(Coordinate *location) 
{
    location->x = 10;
    location->y = 20;
    functB(&location);
}

void functB(Coordinate *location)
{
    location->x = location->x/2;
    location->y = location->y/2;
}
```

The output is still `x = 10`, and `y = 20` when I want it to be `5` and `10`.

Could I get some help?

Answer (score 2):

You've already received a pointer to the structure, you don't need to use the `&` operand again. So it should be just `functB(location);`.

Answer (score 2):

In `functA()`, `location` is already a pointer. When you use the address of operator on `location` again, you are asking for the memory address that stores that pointer. So, you're not passing `functB` a `Coordinate*`, you're passing a `Coordinate**`.

The fix is to not use `&` when passing it to `functB`

```
functB(&location);
```

becomes

```
functB(location);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
functB(&location);
```

On `functA` you get `Coordinate *location`, meaning an adress to a `Coordinate`, named `location`. The in said line, you pass `&location`, which is an adress to `location`, which is in turn, an addres to `Coordinate`.
Just change it to:

```
functB(location);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `functA` you have this line:

```
 functB(&location);
```

This passes the address to the pointer into `functB` making this a pointer to a pointer. Simply remove the `&`:

```
functB(location);
```